# Is there any way to disable the "auto stage unstaged changes on commit if nothing is staged" feature in Git in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have some changes I definitely don't want to commit (production connection strings), and I'm afraid I'll accidentally commit them. In Mercurial I'd simply ignore them, but in git for VS2017 the only way to do this it seems is to make another change and stage that change; if I leave all changes unstaged then git "helpfully" automatically auto-stages all of them for me. So is there any way to disable the auto-stage feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not.  But even if there was, this still sounds rather error prone.  Some commands, like rebase, will refuse to operate if you have modified working directory files.

You can also ignore changes to files that are committed in git.  (Not using the `.gitignore` functionality, since that only works with untracked files.)  Instead, you can set the "assume unchanged" bit on a file.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

Like the name implies, git will now assume that the file is not changed, and it will be ignored by commands like `git status` (and like the Visual Studio Team Explorer).

However, my best suggestion would be to refactor your configuration so that it pulls in these connection strings from a local file that you can `.gitignore`.